# Como resuelvo un sistema de ecuaciones no lineales en c#?

Tags: c#

necesito ayuda para resolver un sistema de ecuaciones no lineales por algun metodo. probe por newton rhapson pero no me sirvio. y tengo entendido que esta por eliminacion gaussiana igual pero no se como implementarlo, este es mi sistema de ecuaciones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
    double z,x, y, f1, f2, f3, variable_criterio = 0.001;
                double pivote, factor;
                double[,] matriz = new double[3,4];
    
                x = 1;
                y = 2;
                z = 3;
                f1 = (y * Math.Cos(x + y) - x);
                f2 = (x * Math.Pow(2.7183, (x + z)) - y);
                f3 = ((x * z) + (y * z) + (x + y));
    
                while (Math.Abs(f1) > variable_criterio | Math.Abs(f2) > variable_criterio | Math.Abs(f3) > variable_criterio)
                {
                    f1 = (y * Math.Cos(x + y) - x);
                    f2 = (x * Math.Pow(2.7183, (x + z)) - y);
                    f3 = ((x * z) + (y * z) + (x + y));
    
                    matriz[0, 0] = (-x*Math.Sin(x+y)-1);
                    matriz[0, 1] = (-y*Math.Sin(x+y));
                    matriz[0, 2] = Math.Cos(y+x);
                    matriz[0, 3] = -f1;
                    matriz[1, 0] = (Math.Pow(2.7183,(x+z))*x + Math.Pow(2.7183,(x+z)));
                    matriz[1, 1] = -1;
                    matriz[1, 2] = Math.Pow(2.7183,(x+z)*x);
                    matriz[1, 3] = -f2;
                    matriz[2, 0] = (z-y);
                    matriz[2, 1] = (z-x);
                    matriz[2, 2] = (x+y);
                    matriz[2, 3] = -f3;
    
                    
                    //Eliminación Gaussiana //------------------------------
                    for (int reng = 0; reng < 3; reng = reng + 1)
                    {
                        pivote = matriz[reng, reng];
                        for (int colu = 0; colu < 4; colu = colu + 1)
                        {
                            matriz[reng, colu] = matriz[reng, colu] / pivote;
                        }
                        for (int reng_elimi = 0; reng_elimi < 2; reng_elimi = reng_elimi + 1)
                        {
                            if (reng_elimi != reng)
                            {
                                factor = matriz[reng_elimi, reng];
                                for (int colu_elimi = 0; colu_elimi < 3;
                                    colu_elimi = colu_elimi + 1)
                                {
                                    matriz[reng_elimi, colu_elimi] = matriz[reng_elimi,
                                       colu_elimi] - factor * matriz[reng, colu_elimi];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //------------------------------
    
                    x = x + matriz[0, 3];
                    y = y + matriz[1, 3];
                    z = z + matriz[2, 3];
                }
    
                Console.WriteLine("El valor final de x es: " + x);
                Console.WriteLine("El valor final de y es: " + y);
                Console.WriteLine("El valor final de y es: " + z);
    
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

resolvi la matriz que me quedo por el metodo de gauss jordan y los resultados que obtengo son diferentes a los que me retorna el programa, es por eso que no tengo muy claro como resolverlo.

igual si alguien me puede aportar algun otro metodo que considere prudente para resolver me puede decir, se lo agradeceria.

debe ser en c# aunque igual si tiene una idea en otro lenguaje yo vere la manera de traducirlo, gracias

Comment: Tal vez este link pueda ayudarte: http://acodigo.blogspot.com/2014/03/gauss-jordan.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El codigo es de la siguiente manera:

```
    //SE DECLARAN LAS VARIABLES QUE SE USARAN A LO LARGO DEL CODIGO, EPSILON ES NUESTRA VARIABLE DE ERROR ESTANDAR COMO SE LE CONOCE EN ESTADISTICA 
    double x, y, z, f1, f2, f3, epsilon = 0.0001;

    // AMBAS ECUACIONES SON VARIABLES QUE REQUIERE EL METODO, PARA GUARDAR LOS VALORES DE LAS POSICIONES SEGUN SEA LA ITERACION
    double pivote, factor;

    //DECLARAMOS LA MATRIZ, RECORDEMOS QUE ES UN SISTEMA DE 3*3 PERO LE AGREGAMOS LA COLUMNA DE LA MATRIZ AUMENTADA, LA QUE SIRVE PARA SABER LOS VALORES DE LAS INCOGNITAS
    double[,] matriz = new double[3,4];

    // INICIALIZAMOS LAS VARIABLES, LES DAMOS VALORES ALEATORIOS POR QUE EN BASE AL GRAFICO TIENE INFINITAS RAICES
    x = 10;
    y = 20;
    z = 30;
    // SE ESCRIBEN LAS ECUACIONES DEL SISTEMA, PERO IGUALADAS YA A CERO
    f1 = (((y)*Math.Cos(x+y))- (x));
    f2 = (((x)*Math.Exp(x+z))- (y));
    f3 = ((x * z) + (y * z) - (x * y));
    //SE REPETIRA EL CICLO HASTA LOS VALORES ABOSOLUTOS DE CUALQUIER FUNCION SEA MAYOR AL VALOR DE EPSION (ERROR ESTANDAR)  ES DECIR MUY SIMILAR A CERO PARA ACERCARNOS LO MAS 
    //POSIBLE AL RESULTADO MAS EXACTO
    while (Math.Abs(f1) > epsilon | Math.Abs(f2) > epsilon | Math.Abs(f3) > epsilon)
    {
        // LOS VALORES DE LAS ECUACIONES CAMBIARAN EN CADA ITERACION Y ES POR ESO QUE LAS DECLARAMOS DENTRO DEL WHILE IGUAL PARA HACERLAS DINAMICAS
        f1 = (((y)*Math.Cos(x+y))- (x));
        f2 = (((x)*Math.Exp(x+z))- (y));
        f3 = ((x * z) + (y * z) - (x * y));

        //RECORDEMOS QUE DECLARAMOS UNA MATRIZ, AQUI SE USA Y EN CADA POSCION PONEMOS LAS DERIVADAS CON RESPECTO A CADA INCOGNITA Y EN LA ULTIMA COLUMNA AUMENTADA
        //IRA LA INVERSA DE LOS VALORES Y DE AHI NACE EL SIGNO -FN

        matriz[0, 0] =  (((-y) * Math.Sin(x + y)) - 1);
        matriz[0, 1] = (((-y) * Math.Sin(x + y)) + (Math.Cos(x + y)));
        matriz[0, 2] = 0;
        matriz[0, 3] = (-f1);
        matriz[1, 0] = ((x * Math.Exp(x + z)) + (Math.Exp(x + z)));
        matriz[1, 1] = -1;
        matriz[1, 2] = x * Math.Exp(x + z);
        matriz[1, 3] = -f2;
        matriz[2, 0] = z - y;
        matriz[2, 1] = z - x;
        matriz[2, 2] = x + y;
        matriz[2, 3] = -f3;

        //METODO YA ESTABLECIDO,PERO CAMBIAMOS LOS VALORES QUE HABIAN DE 2 Y 3 EN LOS REGLONES Y COLUMNAS SEGUN EL TAMANIO DE LA MATRIZ
        
        //Eliminación Gaussiana //------------------------------

        for (int reng = 0; reng < 3; reng ++)
        {
            pivote = matriz[reng, reng];
            for (int colu = 0; colu < 4; colu ++)
            {
                matriz[re          ng, colu] = matriz[reng, colu] / pivote;
            }

            for (int reng_elimi = 0; reng_elimi < 3; reng_elimi ++)
            {
                if (reng_elimi != reng)
                {
                    factor = matriz[reng_elimi, reng];
                    for (int colu_elimi = 0; colu_elimi < 4; colu_elimi = colu_elimi + 1)
                    {
                        matriz[reng_elimi, colu_elimi] = matriz[reng_elimi, colu_elimi]
                                                         - factor * matriz[reng, colu_elimi];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        //FIN DEL CICLO, EN ESTE PUNTO YA SE CONOCEN LOS VALORES DE LAS INCOGNITAS
        
        //------------------------------ Termina Gauss Jordan ------------------------------        
        
        //LOS VALORES DE LAS INCOGNITAS SERA IGUAL AL VALOR O NUMERO QUE HAYA QUEDADO EN LA COLUMNA AUMENTADA DE LA MATRIZ, ES DECIR LA ULTIMA COLUMAN
        
        x = x + matriz[0, 3];
        y = y + matriz[1, 3];
        z = z + matriz[2, 3];
    }

    //MOSTRAMOS LOS VALORES DE CADA VARIABLE
    Console.WriteLine("El valor final de x es: " + x);
    Console.WriteLine("El valor final de y es: " + y);
    Console.WriteLine("El valor final de z es: " + z);
```